# How to make NSSlider be vertical programmatically?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I write a Mac app and create some NSSlider programmatically. The default NSSlider's orientation is horizontal. 
How can I make NSSlider be vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Objective C**

I did it by using this:

```
self.yourSlider.frameRotation = 90.0;
CGRect frame = self.yourSlider.frame;
float tmp = frame.size.height;
frame.size.height = frame.size.width;
frame.size.width = tmp;
[self.yourSlider setFrame:frame];
[self.yourSlider setWantsLayer:TRUE];
```

**Swift**

And I guess the Swift version will be:

```
self.yourSlider.frameRotation = 90.0
var frame: CGRect = self.yourSlider.frame
var tmp: Float = frame.size.height
frame.size.height = frame.size.width
frame.size.width = tmp
self.yourSlider.frame = frame
self.yourSlider.setWantsLayer(TRUE)
```

Comment: UISlider has transform property but I can find it in a NSSlider.

Comment: Thanks. It's worked. And self.yourSlider.frame = frame. I forgot to edit it.